# How get date and time from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm using React and from the Firebase database. I would like to ask how could I get information (date and time) from firebase and add it to my project?

I couldn't find it in the firebase documentation or maybe I looked wrong.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id");
// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a timestamp that you've stored already? If you just want the current time, you should be getting it from the browser via `new Date()`.

Comment: @nVitius While you can uses a browser time, that can be spoofed and inaccurate data would then be present and anything that's is time sensitive could be at risk.

Answer (score 2):

A great solution is to use a Firestore server timestamp - it's server based and cannot be manipulated by the user

This question is tagged 'Firebase' and Firebase represents a LOT of different products so a specific answer is impossible.

Here's a link to the Firestore docs for a [Server Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) there are corresponding functions for other platforms as well as shown in that document.

Here's how it looks in Java

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id");
// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
ApiFuture<WriteResult> writeResult = docRef.update("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
System.out.println("Update time : " + writeResult.get());
```